# Using class level @PreAuthorized annotations alongside method level @PreAuthorzied annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to get a @PreAuthorized annotation on a controller class to work in conjunction with a @PreAuthorized annotation on methods (endpoints) of the same class. 
The overview of the class looks something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@PreAuthorized("hasRole('CLASS_LEVEL_ROLE')")
public class foo { 

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @PreAuthorized("hasRole('METHOD_LEVEL_ROLE')")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<String> bar() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("entered method successfully");    
    }
}
```

Currently what is happening is only the method level annotation is being taken into account.

Ideally what would happen is only users with role 'CLASS_LEVEL_ROLE' **and** 'METHOD_LEVEL_ROLE' would be allowed access to bar().

I'm aware I could use

`@PreAuthorized("hasRole('CLASS_LEVEL_ROLE') and hasRole('METHOD_LEVEL_ROLE')")`

but  I have some controllers where all endpoints would have to have the same `'CLASS_LEVEL_ROLE'` and it would be more convenient to have a generalized class annotation.

Answer (score 9):

@PreAuthorize allows a class level annotation. The way it is supposed to work is that if a method level annotation exists, it will override the class level annotation. You can't do a union of both. So a class level annotation can be seen as a fallback when a method level annotation is not present.

Comment: Hi @Vinay Avasthi, thank you for the reply, I am aware that this is the default behavior but is there any configuration that could be used to change this type of behavior or any known workaround, all of my searches have been unsuccessful

Comment: @vega2015 did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Solution could be a custom implementation of @PreAuthorize. It is not so hard to implement custom annotation and add aspect which will be used before method.